# elasticsearch nest : get number results of SearchRequest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am looking for how to do an elasticsearch _count for nest :

in elastic seatch it would be:

i am looking for the equivalent of:

```cs
var request = new SearchRequest<type>()
{
            Query = new BoolQuery
            {
                //Should = ...
                //Must = ...
            },
            MinScore = 1
           //....
    };
var nbResult = client.Count(request);
```

If you know how to do it and if you have a tip for having a count of results with the fastest way it would help me a lot.

Comment: You should get total documents with search or all you need its just count?

Comment: i would like to prevent to load all documents if it is possible

Comment: Silly suggestion would set size to 0. I see that there was in  old api https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/count.html

Comment: this link is a tip for limiting the size of the answere ,i want to have the size of the answers if all answere were returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `client.Count<T>( ... )`

```cs
var request = new CountRequest<Document>
{
    Query = new MatchAllQuery()
};

var nbResult = client.Count<Document>(request);
```

which yields the following request

```
POST http://localhost:9200/default-index/document/_count
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I think his problem is that he want SearchRequest to be casted to CountRequest.  Is that possible?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat no, they're two different queries. You can send a search request with `size: 0` as you have suggested which would achieve the same result and use the `_search` API. There used to be a `search_type: "count"` for the `_search` API but it was deprecated in 2.0 and removed in 5.0. See https://github.com/jpountz/elasticsearch/commit/a608db122de8f2a8fb4df6131395894c7b39428a

Comment: @RussCam thank you for answere but I would like to have number of result for a specific SearchRequest , not the total number of doc. My elasticsearch sample in my question is wrong

Comment: @RussCam Ok, I finally understood I must give a QueryContainer to Query Property in CountRequest

Comment: @RussCam is it normal that I have an empty # Request  in DebugInformation in the answere of a CountAsync Request?

Answer (score 0):

I found in sources. Its not solution because i cant test it locally but at least direction.

Look to this [test](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/02bdf28788e657cffc253598d7766820f9eed62e/src/Nest/Search/Count/ElasticClient-Count.cs) and [client source](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/02bdf28788e657cffc253598d7766820f9eed62e/src/Nest/Search/Count/ElasticClient-Count.cs)